# AMP HTML timeout event to close lightbox after some time

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible in AMP HTML to close `amp-lightbox` component after a time delay? 
I have a lightbox shown after form submission success and I want to close it automatically after e.g. 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with amp-lightbox, but you could build this using amp-bind and amp-animation. The basic idea is:

- define a multi-step amp-animation that shows and hides the lightbox
- start the animation on form submit success

Which would look like this:

```
<amp-animation id="snackbarSlideIn" layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "duration": "500",
      "fill": "both",
      "easing": "ease-out",
      "iterations": "1",
      "selector": ".snackbar",
      "keyframes": [{
          "transform": "translateY(-100%)"
        },
        {
          "transform": "translateY(0)"
        }
      ],
      "animation": "snackbarSlideOut"
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>
<amp-animation id="snackbarSlideOut" layout="nodisplay">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "delay": "3s",
      "duration": "500",
      "fill": "both",
      "easing": "ease-in",
      "iterations": "1",
      "selector": ".snackbar",
      "keyframes": [{
          "transform": "translateY(0)"
        },
        {
          "transform": "translateY(-100%)"
        }
      ]
    }
  </script>
</amp-animation>
<div class="snackbar">
  Success
</div>

<form on="submit-success:snackbarSlideIn.start" ...>...</form>
```

[Here](https://jsbin.com/bihumomeyi/edit?html,output) is a sample demonstrating how to use this approach to create a [snackbar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html) with AMP.

Answer (score 0):

No mention of delays in [closing the lightbox](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-lightbox#closing-the-lightbox):

> Pressing the escape key on the keyboard will close the lightbox.
>   Alternatively setting the on attribute on one or more elements within
>   the lightbox and setting its method to close will close the lightbox
>   when the element is tapped or clicked.

Comment: @sebastianbenz - I tried your code but for some reason only the animation from the second animation (snackbarSlideOut) is visible. If i remove this animation and the reference to it in snackbarSlideIn, then the first animation is visible. Any idea why? ( I checked the JSBin and it seems to be suffering from the same issue - the black bar just pops up with no animation, but it disappears with the second animation fine)