# Can AMP HTML amp-animation be triggered on state conditional true?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, amp-html

I have set a state property which is an array that has a length of 0-2. I am able to set this just fine and test against it when adding classes to an element like so:

1. `<a [class]="arrayOfOptions.length < 1 ? 'container disabled' : 'container'" ...>`

This works fine. However I am trying to add an `<amp-animation>` very similar to the animation described here [AMP HTML timeout event to close lightbox after some time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929235/amp-html-timeout-event-to-close-lightbox-after-some-time/48093856#48093856) and here is the JS Bin page: https://jsbin.com/bihumomeyi/edit?html,output .

From the animation example I see that to trigger the animation I need to do something like this:

2. `<button on="tap:snackbarSlideIn.start">Show Snackbar</button>`

What I want to do is to allow the animation to take place ONLY if arrayOfOptions.length > 1. I was hoping there would be some syntax to allow this like the following pseudocode where I want to test that .length is greater than 1 before starting the animation (a marriage of #1 and #2 code snippets above):

3. `<button on="tap:arrayOfOptions.length > 1 ? snackbarSlideIn.start : do nothing">Show Snackbar</button>`

Is this possible in AMP HTML at all? If not, can someone provide an alternative solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't really tested this, but I encountered something similar to yours. So what I did was duplicating the elements but with different hidden attributes. I know it's ugly but works for me. Probably something like this:

`<button [hidden]="arrayOfOptions.length > 1">Show Snackbar</button>`
`<button [hidden]="arrayOfOptions.length <= 1" on="tap:snackbarSlideIn.start">Show Snackbar</button>`

Comment: I see so your approach is to use two elements, hide one and show the other depending on the case. It seems it should work thank you for the suggestion.

But to answer my question: NO there is no way to do that I'm assuming?